# Intellij no actualiza los cambios en el navegador

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

Esoty trabajando en una aplicacion Java web, y cada vez que realizo un cambio en el codigo y actualizo, en el navegador no se ve ese cambio, he intentando ya muchas cosas pero nada lo unica solucion que he encontrado es elimnar el cache desde el navegador pero se supone que esto no deberia sera asi. Estoy usando un servidor tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ocupas Firefox o Chrome puedes deshabilitar el cache cada vez que habilites las herramientas de desarrollador. De otro modo también puedes hacer un Filter que ponga el cache header en 0 y de ese modo el navegador no hará cache a nada.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]